# ffmpeg - Extract Video filesize from virtual data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, filesize, simulate

I am trying to calculate a video filesize from its data using [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Assuming that I have the following data in my disposal :

- `vcodec => mp4a.40.2`
- `acodec => avc1.64001F`
- `format_note => hd720`
- `height => 720`
- `width => 1280`
- `ext => mp4`
- `duration => 56 (seconds)`

**Questions :**

1. Is there any mathematical formula that can extract the video
   filesize using the data above
2. Is it possible to simulate and extract the filesize of a
   non-existing file using the data above
3. If FFMPEG cannot accomplish what Im asking, what do you suggest ?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the filesize of a video you to know the bitrate and the video length, bitrate is usually in kb/s so you need to multiply that value for the amount of seconds in the video.

If your video contains audio, you should also consider it for the filesize using the same approach.

If you don't know the bitrate you are going to use for encoding, you should check the encoder you are going to use and check for it's default values. But the most secure way is to define your own bitrate and make sure the size will be what you expect.

Comment: Thank for your helpful answer. Can you tell me if there is a default bitrate for both video and audio codecs that i mentionned in my question ? Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to encode? I think you are doing something for the web, right? I think the better approach is for you to define your own desired bitrate when encoding so your calculations can be more exact.

Comment: Thank you for your smartness, you just gave me the idea to re-encode the video with a given bitrate. Indeed it is for web. So know the question is : 1- Whats the FFMPEG command to re-encode a video (audio included) to mp4 with a specific bitrate. 2- Is there a specific bitrate for every video quality (i dont want to lose quality for 720p / 1080p for example). Thank you @Maxito

Comment: Refer to this link for h264 encoding options overview https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 For bitrate you can use -b:v <videoBitrateValue> and -b:a <audioBitrateValue> To maintain constant bitrate (CBR) and have more exact calculations refer to this part of the link https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#CBRConstantBitRate